# Add tag synonym [opposite] for tag [antonym]

Tags: feature-request, tagging, tag-synonyms

I actually had to open another question with "opposite" in its title to figure out what tag to use for my [What's the opposite of "server"/"server operating system"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30976/whats-the-opposite-of-server-server-operating-system) question. I think it would be a valuable addition to the site if there was a tag synonym [opposite](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opposite) for the existing tag [antonym](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antonym).

Answer (score 1):

When a tag is made a synonym of another one, and users enter the first tag, it will be replaced with the second one. For the system is like the first tag doesn't exist at all.

Adding a synonym of a tag is done when there are users who use two different tags, but both the tags have the same meaning, or when users write a tag using the wrong spelling. It could also be used when questions are migrated from another site that uses tags different from the tags already in use in the site where the question is migrated, and there is a correspondence between the tags; in this case, the synonym is created when there enough migrated questions that use that tag.
In other cases, it doesn't make sense to create a synonym, as (apart the cases I have already reported) it doesn't add any value.

Comment: I know this. I want to be able to write "opposite" which will then appear as "antonym". That's what I'm asking here. Sorry for the unprecise question, I'll make an edit.

Comment: @Felix What is the purpose? Do you have a keyboard that doesn't allow you to write _antonym_? `;-)`

Comment: I am an advanced user who is able and (a bit) willing to look up questions similar to one I am about to post and look at their tags. However, generally, if I write a question about something, say, opposites, and I'm beginning to write "oppo" but no tag suggestion comes up, I am quite annoyed. I think many are, and I think it is reasonable to assume that most would indeed use the word "opposite" before thinking of the term "antonym". Therefore, it adds value. It's not about my keyboard. It's about my mind.

Comment: @Felix You know that the tag is [tag:antonyms], and you even used it. Synonyms are used if there is a problem to solve, not because somebody feels annoyed by trying to look for questions tagged [tag:opposite], and noticing that the tag is not auto completed.

Comment: I didn't know it before, and using it was HARD, as there was an unnecessary step. Also, your example doesn't reflect what I was saying: I wasn't looking for questions tagged opposite, I was trying to tag my own question. Actually, I would even go so far as to say "We have a tag here. Wait, there exists a synonym for the tag? Let's add it as a tag synonyme as well then." I honestly think that it improves usability, is especially helpful to new users, and I don't know any downsides. Why do you oppose so strictly? My proposal covers *exactly* what tag synonyms were created for.

Comment: Tag synonyms were not created to allow everybody to choose the tag synonym they like better. Every SE site has a list of tags; if you don't know which tag to use, you can look at the list, which reports also a short description of the tag. The reason "it was hard for me to find the tag to use in my question" doesn't sound as a reason to create a synonym, especially now that you know which tag you should use ([tag:antonyms]). The next time you ask a question for which the tag [tag:antonyms] is necessary, you will remember that the tag is [tag:antonyms], not [tag:opposite].